# Can we use Windows UI Automation API to automate web page in Internet Explorer?

Tags: c#, browser-automation

We have a web application and we want to use Windows Native UI Automation API for .Net to automate that.

I've been looking into this for hours, but couldn't find anything. I can get to the windows parts of the internet explorer, like menu, minimize button, maximize button, close button etc but not able to go inside the page opened. I am wondering if it is possible at all. If it is, then can someone please point me to the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use that specific tool / API?

Comment: It is a requirement, but i am open to other tools. I tried to use Selenium but it doesn't allow to connect to the existing opened browser

Comment: I have come across the need to do this myself in the past, and what we've always done is to build a desktop application using either WinForms or WPF. We put a browser control into the application. You can interact with the browser control do anything you need (click buttons, scroll, fill in forms, etc etc..)

Comment: @mituw16, Yes that can be one alternative but I am afraid we can't do that for this specific case

Comment: @MuhammadAsif Selenium allows to communicate with opened browser.

Comment: @sinitram, can you please share some code or any link to a tutorial or blog post that shows how to do that? Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadAsif I've started with this https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/C%23+Test+Setup+Example

Comment: @sinitram, thanks for link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [WatiN](https://sourceforge.net/projects/watin/) along with Windows Automation API. Thanks everyone who showed interest in this. Appreciate it.